# Cannot get MassTransit response after successfully initiating request

Tags: .net-core, masstransit

I am implementing request/response with MassTransit and Amazon MQ. The (.NET 6 WebApi) host is configured like:

```
services
    .AddMassTransit(x =>
    {
        x.AddConsumer<ConfigurationConsumer>();
        x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
        {
            cfg.Host(new Uri($"amqps://{rabbitMqSettings.Host}:{rabbitMqSettings.Port}/{Uri.EscapeDataString("/vhostname")}"), h =>
            {
                h.Username(rabbitMqSettings.Username);
                h.Password(rabbitMqSettings.Password);
            });
            cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
        });
        x.AddRequestClient<IConfigurationCommand>();
    })
    .AddMassTransitHostedService();
```

The client uses the same configuration without x.AddConsumer() and           cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context).

The problem is: calling GetResponse on the client will successfully execute the consumer on the host which seems to respond as intended, but the client never gets a result and times out.

On the other hand, when I am using a web api controller on the same host to initiate GetResponse, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that the message types between the host and the client applications are the same.

ALSO, make sure the bus is started on the client using the hosted service or otherwise.

Comment: They are the same (from a common assembly). I noticed, that there is an exchange but no queue to transport the response back to the client. The web api controller (which works fine) seems to provide a queue with the same name as the exchange.

Comment: no queue, typically means you didn't start the bus.

Comment: I use .AddMassTransitHostedService() on the client, too. Maybe the host is still not started correctly, can I check that somehow?

Comment: You should see the bus started in the logs.

Comment: Thank you a lot that was it, or rather: I messed up wiring the services in the client (console) which somehow inhibited the host from starting. I redid the console following [MS: generic host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/generic-host) and now it works like a charm.